# What are the mathematics I need to learn, before I start research in data mining

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, information-retrieval

I usually use text mining, graph mining, Information retrieval, and natural lanuage processing. Also i will use the fundamental concepts of data mining like classification, association and clustering. Please suggest me solution and study material( text books).